# Send sms after call rejection - being sent multiple times

Tags: android, telephonymanager, smsmanager

I want to send SMS after reject incoming call. 
App is sending the SMS but the problem is that it is sending it twice. I am unable to figure out where problem is.

Below is the code used.

```
public class CallBarring extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private String number;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // If, the received action is not a type of "Phone_State", ignore it
         if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) 
             return;

        // Else, try to do some action
         else 
         {
             // Fetch the number of incoming call
             number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

             // Check, whether this is a member of "Black listed" phone numbers stored in the database
            if(MainActivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number)))
             {
                 // If yes, invoke the method
                 disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                 sendSMS(context);
               //  return;
             }else{
                 disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                 sendSMS(context);

             }
         }  
    }

    public void sendSMS(Context context) {

        try{
        String message = SharedPrefActivity.CommonMethod.getPrefsData(context, SharedPrefActivity.Constants.TextMessage, "");

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,CallBarring.class);  
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,0);  
        SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();  
        sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, pi,null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }

    // Method to disconnect phone automatically and programmatically 
    // Keep this method as it is 
     @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
     private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context) 
     {
         ITelephony telephonyService;
         TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
         context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
         try 
         {
             Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
             Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
             m.setAccessible(true);
             telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
             telephonyService.endCall();
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but aren't the code in your if and else block the same? So what's the point?

Comment: `MainActivity.blockList` is it static ? if it is, how are you filling it ? You are calling same condition of disconnect and send sms, so why it is ?

Comment: code does not work....

Comment: let remove else part then cant work

Comment: remove else part.. but same condition issue plz help sir....

Comment: i am trying from two days....

Comment: Please give 10 mins I'm constructing a similar app so give me 10 mins

Comment: sir what happens..any solution

Comment: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE will be called multiple times. so you have to check if it`s for rejection

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
// Check, whether this is a.   member of "Black listed" phone.   numbers stored in the database
            if(MainActivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number)))
     {
         // If yes, invoke the method
                 disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
         sendSMS(context);
       //  return;
     }else{
                 disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
         sendSMS(context);

     }
```

This to

```
// Check, whether this is a.       member of "Black listed" phone.       numbers stored in the database
                if(MainActivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number)))
     {
         // If yes, invoke the method
                 disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
sendSMS(context)
         }
```

Comment: remove else part.  same condition issue plz help me.... im am trying from two days